# Changing navigation title programmatically

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, title

I have a navigation bar with a title.
When I double click the text to rename it, it actually says it's a navigation item, so it might be that.

I'm trying to change the text using code, like:

```
declare navigation bar as navagationbar here
button stuff {
    navigationbar.text = "title"
}
```

That's not my code obviously, just showing how it would work.

So whenever I press the button, I want the title to change.

Answer (score 617, accepted):

You change the title by changing the [title](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/title) of the view controller being displayed:

```
viewController.title = "some title"
```

Normally this is done in view did load on the view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "some title"
}
```

However, this only works if you have your view controller embedded in a UINavigationController. I **highly** recommend doing this instead of creating a navigation bar yourself. If you insist on creating a navigation bar yourself, you can change the title by doing:

```
navigationBar.topItem.title = "some title"
```

Comment: ViewController.type does not have a member named title. That's the error I get.

Comment: You don't call it directly on the class. You call it on an instance of a subclass of UIViewController

Comment: Yes, `ViewController` refers to the class itself. You need to refer to an **instance** of `ViewController`. From within a method on your class, such as `viewDidLoad`, you can do so using `self`. If you do not know the difference between a class and an instance, I highly recommend you learn what it is. [This article](http://alfredjava.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/class-vs-object-vs-instance/) will help.

Comment: Works like a charm in Xcode as well.. just a small change -> self.title = @"some title";

Comment: self.title = "some title" worked for me. Thank you ! I have been trying 'navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "Some title". really not sure why it doesn't work. (I do have a navigation item there,which I placed to display the title, in addition to the embedded navigation controller ). I still think it should work, but dont know why. Stack overflow to the rescue once again !

Comment: @Naishta navigationItem is a part of every UIViewController. A navigation controller shows the navigation item of the current view controller. You other code is setting the navigationItem on the navigation controller itself which would only apply if another navigation controller was trying to display your navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks. I was using self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Settings" but this works just as well and is simpler.

Comment: @drewag what is the reasoning behind this statement please? : "I highly recommend doing this instead of creating a navigation bar yourself".

Comment: @oyalhi I have experienced several bugs in the past from not using a navigation controller. Most have been related to OS upgrades. The less custom view programming you can do, the more resilient your app will be to OS upgrades. For example, I saw lots of issues (I am a contract developer so i work on many projects) during the transition to the new style status bar. I had to do a lot of shifting of views down but a UINavigationController did this automatically because Apple did it for us.

Comment: Warning: `self.title = "some title"` will change the navigation bar title AND the tab bar item title.

Comment: @drewag, could you help my problem please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304498/how-to-set-font-family-to-uiviewcontroller-title-in-swift ?

Comment: and use this to change title of navigation bar title in a tab bar :   `tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "title"`

Comment: shouldn't this be in viewWillAppear()?

Answer (score 84):

Try the following in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.navigationItem.title = "Your Title"
```

Comment: Work for me. iOS 11.4

Answer (score 21):

The code below works for me with Xcode 7:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {        
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = "Your Title"
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I found this to work:

```
navigationItem.title = "Title"
```

Comment: How do you center the title in a view controller which is a child of a UINavigationController? For some reason the text is aligned to the left.  `var customTitle =  self.navigationController?.visibleViewController?.navigationItem          
        customTitle?.title = "Some Title"`

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 5.1**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "What ever you want"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have a `NavigationController` embedded inside of a `TabBarController` see below:

```
super.tabBarController?.title = "foobar"
```

[image]

You can debug issues like this with debugger scripts. Try [Chisel's](https://github.com/facebook/chisel) `pvc` command to print every visible / hidden view on the hierarchy.

Answer (score 6):

and also if you will try to create `Navigation Bar` manually this code will help you

```
func setNavBarToTheView() {
    let navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 64.0))
    self.view.addSubview(navBar);
    let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Camera");
    let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.cancel, target: self, action: #selector(CameraViewController.onClickBack));
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneItem;
    navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: true);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer for people using [swift4](/questions/tagged/swift4) would be

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = "Your Text"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Normally, the best-practice is to set the title on the `UIViewController`.  By doing this, the `UINavigationItem` is also set.  Generally, this is better than programmatically allocating and initializing a `UINavigationBar` that's not linked to anything.

You miss out on some of the benefits and functionality that the `UINavigationBar` was designed for. [Here is a link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uinavigationbar_class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/topItem) to the documentation that may help you.  It discusses the different properties you can set on the actual bar and on a `UINavigationItem`.

Just keep in mind:

1. You lose back button functionality (unless you wire it yourself)
2. The built-in "drag from the left-hand side to swipe back" gesture is forfeited

`UINavigationController`'s are your friends.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted to change the title from a child view controller of a Page View Controller that's embedded in a navigation controller, it would look like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.parent?.title = "some title"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3**

I created an outlet for the navigation title bar item that comes with the navigation bar (from the Object Browser) in the storyboard. Then I sued the line below:

```
navigationBarTitleItem.title = "Hello Bar"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have not created navigation bar in your view controller from storyboard this will work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Title"
}
```

If you have created navigation bar in your view controller from storyboard this will be helpful.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Title"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5.1**

// Set NavigationBar Title Programmatically and Dynamic

**Note :**
First add NavigationControllerItem to Your `ViewController` then goto their `ViewController.swift` file and Just Copy and Paste this in `viewDidLoad()`.

`navigationItem.title = "Your Title Here"`

e.g.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Your Title Here"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Just connect an outlet to your nav bar and access the title through the topItem

```
navBar.topItem?.title = "Your Title Here"
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `self.navigationItem.title = "Your Title Here"` over `self.title = "Your Title Here"` to provide title in the navigation bar since tab bar also uses `self.title` to alter its title. You should try the following code once.

**Note: calling the super view lifecycle is necessary before you do any stuffs.**

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupNavBar()
    }
}

private func setupNavBar() {
    self.navigationItem.title = "Your Title Here"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in viewDidLoad

navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Your Text"

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4:

**Swift 4**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Your title"
}
```

I hope it helps, regards!

Comment: This is just half of the accepted answer. Also, if you say that nothing changed, then why would you post anything?! Please delete.

Comment: @Moritz are you moderator or something like that? if say Yes, I will delete it, if not I will not delete it.

Comment: You really say it ?, above me there are 4 completely equal answers, then why do you come with me and tell me to erase mine? I am a trusted user who supports the community, I am not going around just repeating answers. I just wanted to update this question with an updated swift version.

Comment: There’s nothing updated in your answer. This is the same code as the accepted answer, the “Normally this is done in view did load” part...

Answer (score 0):

In viewWillAppear()

```
self.title = "Title here"
```

or you may try this also

if you have navigation controller

```
navigationItem.title = "Title here"
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.

Comment: Hello, this is the standard format to put a title in the navigation bar. No other way to set the title in the navigation bar.

Comment: Yes, I know it's the standard way. But nearly all of the other answers already state this. Your answer doesn't add any new information that doesn't already exist in the other answers. That's why it is a duplicate and should be deleted.

Comment: Duplicate answer.