# Swift Navigation Bar Button and Title don't appear

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, xcode6-beta5

I'd like to create a Navigation bar on top of my App. I created an Navigation Controller -> Tab Bar Controller -> Navigation Controller -> Table Controller

1. I dragged a Bar Button Item on the upper right side.
2. I double clicked the title in the middle of the Table Controller and wrote a text.
3. I also tried it with this code in the viewDidLoad() of my controller:

   ```
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = "some title"
   self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Search, target: self, action: "barButtonItemClicked:"), animated: true)
   self.navigationItem.title = "YourTitle"
   ```

Non of it worked - what am I doing wrong? :/

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 34):

You can try something like this:

```
self.title = "Your Title"

var homeButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "LeftButtonTitle", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "")

var logButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "RigthButtonTitle", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "")

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = homeButton
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = logButton
```

Comment: How can I set an icon instead of text?

Comment: I found how:) --> 
var homeBytton  : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: <#UIImage?#>, style: <#UIBarButtonItemStyle#>, target: <#AnyObject?#>, action: <#Selector#>)

Comment: Remember that you can leave out the `UIBarButtonItemStyle` and just use something like `.Plain`. ...also you should be using `let` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for a `titleView`.

Try:

```
var navBarTitleView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, 44.0))
navBarTitleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
self.navigationItem.titleView = navBarTitleView
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that you can just set the title of your table controller, in its viewDidLoad, which is the title displayed in your navigation bar.

this answer explains a slightly different question, but the concept is the same:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25167491/2070902

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set your **"UINavigationBar"** according to your wish Please follow this very safely ,its so simple in swift language ,hope it will help you a lot .

**STEP 1:-**

Create a category class in swift just go on **"New file"** and add **"Simple swift class "** and given it name **"MyCustomNavBarCategory.swift"**

**STEP 2:-**

Just **"Clean the class (remove all code from this class)"** and **"Paste my give code below"** :-

**//class will Start from  below line**  start copy from here

let SCREEN_HEIGHT = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

import UIKit

extension UINavigationBar {

```
//First increase navigation bar height .
override public func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    NSLog("%f", SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.06);

    let newSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.10)
    return newSize;
}

//then set layOut of your Custom Nav for several objects like titleview,buttons and all
public override func layoutSubviews() {
   for var view in self.subviews
    {
        NSLog("view %@", view);
        let str :String = view.classForCoder.description();
       if(str == "UILabel")
        {
              //play with title view frame
            var f       = view.frame;
            f.origin.y  = self.frame.size.height/2 - view.bounds.size.height/2  ;
            view.frame  = f;
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
        }
        else if(str == "UIButton")
        {

             //play with buttons of navigation bar  view frame
            var f = view.frame;
            f.origin.y = (self.frame.size.height/2)  - (view.bounds.size.height/2) ;
            view.frame = f;
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
        }
    }
}
```

}

//**class will end on above** stop  copy  code on above line and just past this in to your **"MyCustomNavBarCategory.swift"**. that's it enjoy ;).

**STEP 3:-** 
Now you can set any frame to any object of UINavigationBar in this class **"It's very powerful category of UINavigationBar  if you will implement it carefuly"**.