# Unexpected nil for UINavigationItem under unit tests

Tags: ios, swift

I try to test my UIViewController when I set the title:

```
var sut: FloorPlanVC!

override func setUp() {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: “FloorPlan”, bundle: nil)
    sut = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! FloorPlanVC
    _ = sut.view
}

func testSetTitle() {
    sut.title = “Title” //1
    XCTAssertEqual(sut.navigationItem.title, “Title”) //2
}
```

Outputs 1 on console:

```
po sut.title //Title
po sut.navigationItem.title //Title
```

Outputs 2 on console:

```
po sut.title //Title
po sut.navigationItem.title //nil
```

Comment: output 2 when you calling this ? just after output 1 ?

Comment: yes, right after 1

Comment: it is because of navigationItem nil if  your controller is not embedded with tabBarViewController .

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are facing right now is similar to what some people asked with this question:

[Changing navigation title programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167458/changing-navigation-title-programmatically)

Your problem is in a test environment but I think you can relate to it. 
I personally see the issue of the whole set-up being in the test environment leading to you getting unexpected behavior. Check out the answers in the link I gave you, try out which one will work and also let me know.
I was going to just copy them all but no point, you can click the link.