# sending ui data in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller

I'm a bit beginner in SWIFT and right now I'm facing a problem whit UI. In this [PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsuav.png) I'm showing my UI to clarify what I'm saying . in part 1 I check if the user is logged in to his account or not, if yes it goes to part 3, if not it goes to part 2. when user login in part 2, I transfer the user to part 3.
part 1 and 2 should not have any navigation color, though the part 3 should have the navigation color.

**Part 1:**

```
if let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: ConstantsKey.token){
        if !token.isEmpty{
            let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarVC")
            let rootController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            self.present(rootController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVc")
            let rootController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            self.present(rootController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }else{
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVc")
        let rootController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        self.present(rootController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**Part 2:**

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainTabBar", bundle: nil)
                        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarVC")
                        let rootController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                        self.present(rootController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I want to have that red color in part 3 ! but whenever I run the application in shows the defualt color of the navigation controller

**does anybody knows how should I manage/handle this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then in Part 1:

```
    if !token.isEmpty{
                let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarVC")
                let rootController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                rootController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
                self.present(rootController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Part 2:

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainTabBar", bundle: nil)
                        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarVC")
                        let rootController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                        rootController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
                        self.present(rootController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: the red color which is in photo, i mean that

Comment: so sorry to contact u again but I recently found out that the navigation title is not visible! what am I missing here?  even I have defined my title in both my class and in the storyboard.

Comment: hey no problem there is already a question regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167458/changing-navigation-title-programmatically
hope this resolves your problem

Answer (score 0):

**While logging in set**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true,forKey: ConstantsKey.token)
```

**And in routing page check this**

```
if UserDefault.standar.bool(forKey: ConstantsKey.token){
   //Go to home page
}else {
   setUpNav()
   //Go to login page
}
```

**setting navigation**

this one will set for whole app

```
    func setUpNav(){
            UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
            UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
            UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor  = UIColor.white


            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                                                                NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name:"Cairo-Bold", size:22.0)!]
        }
```

if you want for single VC,

write this inside that VC,

**make sure that VC's root is navigationController**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = .red
```

**Even if you haven't set any value, it doesn't crash !!**

Comment: my problem is not with saving the token and the conditions!! my problem is when the user goes to part 3 I want my UI has that red color in part 3

Comment: should I define the last change that you made in first navigation controller or in the first viewcontroller?

Comment: implement it before navigating to the VC you want in red, so you will get the color

Comment: you mean I should put it in PART1 ?

Comment: check the code now ! I have given u two ways to implement the color.
One set's for whole app.-> use this in appDelegate
And other for specific Navigation Controller(the one which need's unique color from default)-> use this inside the VC which you need red color