# How do I change title for navigation bar for image picker page?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using the following code. However when the image picker page comes I get "Photo" instead of "Media Picker" always:

```
    import UIKit
    import AVKit
    import AVFoundation


    class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }


        @IBAction func importLibButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
            let file = UIImagePickerController()
            file.delegate = self
            file.navigationItem.title = "Media Picker"
            file.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary


            file.mediaTypes = ["public.image", "public.movie"]
            file.videoMaximumDuration = 5.0

            file.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(file, animated: true)
            {

            }

        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) 
        {

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }
```

What's possibly wrong here and how do I correct this? I want the imagepicker page to have custom title.

Using navigation controller for the same didn't work too:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(file, animated: true)
```

Comment: Check if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167458/changing-navigation-title-programmatically

Comment: No, I already visited it.

Comment: Is your viewcontroller in a navigationcontroller?

Comment: It's irrelevant here. I know title of navigation item is changed and I have used the same here and it didn't work.

Comment: Ah you are talking about the one you are presenting. You have not presented it in a navigation controller.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, no image picker is a separate page, it opens as gallery, has no view controller here.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, how do i improve my code here for the same to work?

Comment: Use a navigation controller to present the image controller, otherwise the nav bar doesn't exist

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, the present view controller is embedded in navigation controller.

Comment: Yes, but you are presenting another one which is not embedded in a navigation controller. If you were pushing it, then it would use the current navigation controller.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri, I am not getting you. what exactly should I do here then?

Comment: How did you get a navigation bar for the current view? Do the same thing for the new one that you are presenting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180342/discussion-between-doj-yias-lem-and-rakesha-shastri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement UINavigationControllerDelegate method  willShow. You need to check viewControllers.count in navigation controller for showing actual Album name when choosing one (Camera Roll, Moments, etc).

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if navigationController.viewControllers.count == 1 {
        viewController.navigationItem.title = "Media Picker"
    }
}
```